# Monitoring files used by an application?

Tags: windows-xp, monitoring

I need to know which files a Windows application reads/modifies/creates/deletes so I know a bit more about how it works.

Is there a good application for Windows, either free or affordable?

Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the built-in Resource Monitor. Just go to the **Disk** tab and select the checkbox in front of the process you want to monitor.

For a more powerful solution, check out [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645).

Comment: Thanks but I can't find Resource Monitor in XP. Is this a utility that's only available in Vista/7?

Comment: Yes, that's only available in Vista and newer versions. For XP, use Process Monitor. Sorry, I should've asked you to specify the Windows version you were using.

Comment: No problem. Processor Monitor looks like what I was looking for. I'll learn how to filter things further so it only shows files it writes/reads from the filesystem.

Comment: I notice that PM displays a lot of duplicates, but doesn't seem to provide the option of hiding them. Instead of doctoring the log file in LibreOffice's Calc, is there a similar application that can only show unique operations?